# Application Gateway Load balancing mode

Tags: load-balancing, azure, gateway

I have read in the docs (https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/application-gateway-introduction/) that the Load Balancers support sticky sessions where the client will always be routed to the same server for the length of their session.

**My questions:**

1. Is the property `CookieBasedAffinity` on the **Application Gateway** configuration for setting this?
2. Do I set that property to `true` to **enable** sticky sessions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, CookieBasedAffinity is the setting that enables sticky sessions, and it should be set to true, with round robin used for new connections, as per the table in that document:

[image]

Comment: That was what I thought. The table is relatively confusing at first glance. Cheers.